# How can I delegate to scope ? rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, scope, delegates

I have :

```
class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item

  scope :equipped, -> { where(equipped: true) }
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_items
   has_many :users, through: :user_items

   scope :armor, -> { where(type: 'Armor') }
   delegate :equipped, to: :user_items

end
```

EDIT:

If i try

`User.first.items.equipped` => `undefined method 'equipped' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>`

`User.first.items.armor.equipped` => `undefined method 'equipped' for #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`

How can I delegate to scope?

Comment: Hi Matrix, I've updated my answer explaining why you might not actually want to do what you are trying to do, and what approach you need to retrieve child items using the parent scope.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the question, as I'm certain from what you're asking that `merge` is the solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 16):

You can't easily delegate to scopes, nor would you want to since it would return objects from the targeted class (UserItem), not the child.

Instead, you can merge scopes very simply:

```
class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :equipped, -> { where(equipped: true) }
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :equipped, -> {joins(:user_items).merge(UserItem.equipped)} 
end

=> Item.equipped
=> collection of items for which they have a user_item association that is equipped
```

Edit: some documentation on this feature.

[Using Named Scopes Across Models with ActiveRecord#Merge](https://gorails.com/blog/activerecord-merge)
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge

Edit again:

If you REALLY want to return a collection of UserItems from a method you call on Item, then you can do as follows:

```
class Item
  class << self
    delegate :equipped, to: :UserItem
  end 
  ...
```

But this will return UserItems in a collection, not Items. Which begs the question of why delegate this at all?
If you want a collection of Items, and you want to limit those items by a collection of equipped UserItems, then use `merge`.

Comment: If I want use scope in Item, I will use : `scope :equipped, -> {where( inventory_items: { equipped: true }) }` but it's not my question ^^ (I don't downvote)

Comment: @Matrix The scope in my example is in the `Item` model, it joins the user items model and uses the `equipped` scope there to limit the returned `items` by the equipped `user_items`. Unless I'm massively misunderstanding your question, this is what you want? Essentially this does `select items.* from items joins user_items where user_items.equipped = true`.
Do you want to return a collection of `UserItem` objects?

Comment: No, You have understand question, but In Item model I can add : `scope :equipped, -> {where( user_items: { equipped: true }) }` (replace "inventory" by "user", its a mistake in my last com) and it's works fine. But my question is : how use scope in UserItem to not redefine a scope in Item class ?

Comment: You can use `merge` to make use of associated models' scopes without redefining them in the child class. You can't use delegate for scopes.

Comment: @Matrix Alright I'm certain this is either not what you want or is a bad idea but I've added an example that literally passes the `equipped` method straight on to the UserItem class... and the reasoning of why I think it's wrong.

Comment: I don't want UserItem collection. My solution of scope give me a Item collection, fine...